# Word for "make belong"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

What's a verb that means to make object "x" - not necessarily yours, or anyone's for that matter - belong to "y"?

The context is: a phrase that would mean "make keyword belong to this course".

(At first I thought the verb *appropriate* ( = making into property) would mean this, but [I found out](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/appropriate) that it means to denote taking something for yourself or allocating without changing ownership).

Comment: if that's an example of the context in which you want to use the target word, please explain what's wrong with plain old ***give***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: *give* is a technical description of the mechanics and doesn't convey changing owner status.

Comment: @nzn The lightbulb finally went on for me; you don't mean *belong* in the sense of being inherent, you mean in the sense of property. In that case, the most common expression of that concept in English, even used in formal legal contexts, is *transfer ownership*, or as a noun, the *transference of ownership*.

Comment: @Dan Bron: yes exactly. But isn't "transfer" assuming prior ownership? See my edit above and you'll agree that this isn't the case and transfer can't be used.

Comment: @nzn  No, transfer does not imply prior ownership. A bank teller can *transfer* funds from one account to another, without control or ownership of either account or the funds. A shipping company *transfers* cargo from one country to another, but at no point has ownership of the cargo.

Comment: @Dan Bron: ok maybe not ownership but similar prior state. Not applicable in my example.

Comment: @nzn No, I do not agree even if you wave your hands about whether "ownership" is the applicable state. *Transference* only implies an agent, often but not always a disinterested intermediary, not anything analogous to ownership. It is perfectly applicable to your keyword scenario: "*keyword K was transferred to course C*". Or any of the synonyms FF suggested: *assigned*, *alloted*, etx.

Comment: @Dan Bron: possibly, not sure if it refers more to the passage from one similar pre-existing state to a similar state elsewhere than to the internal "legal" state. I may just stick to waving my hands :) Maybe someone else can voice their thoughts on this and convince me.

Comment: ...and everyone else :)

Comment: If you have an answer to your own question, please post the answer with a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I went with was one provided by @FumbleFingers: "assign".

Seeing as I was dealing with abstract terms ("keyword" belong to "course"), I needed a term that described the act of changing the legal state of entity X from not belonging to entity Y to belonging to entity Y, without reference to any previous state or extraneous mechanism.

Suggestions that I didn't adopt:

"Transfer", because it, by definition required that it previously belong to a different entity.

"Give" was the description of a mechanism that wouldn't necessarily effect the required legal change (as entity X can be given to Y while still belonging to Z).